# How to write apply cart rule function

Tags: magento2.4, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have some rules applied to my shopping cart. Assuming the rules have id: 1,2,3,4 and the order in which the rules are applied is 3,2,4,1.
I want to get cart information detail after applied rule 3,2,4 (items price, cart subtotal after applied those 3 rules).

How can i do? Does magento have a function that supports that requirement?

Comment: the cart price rules do have a priority settings. have you tried that?